# Dynamic Row Level Security Using Multiple Columns/Conditions In Power BI

Tags: powerbi, permissions

I have a security table with multiple criteria:

[image]

In the data model, I have a relationship between the user table and the security table. I need to implement the security rules below.

1. IF a user has an admin access level, the company is set to "*" and all other criteria are set to 0. The User should see data as per the matching values of the Security table.
2. If a user has a user access level, the user must be able to see only his data with respective division, location, and department.

I tried the MAXX() function in RLS, but it does not produce the intended results.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that Company/Division/Location/Department/Shift/Project are each independent dimensions.

*If any are attributes/roll-ups, they can be treated as one dimension with a concatenated key ( e.g., `[Company] & "|" & [Division]` >> "67899|1").*

1. Create a separate UPN RLS table for each independent dimension in PowerQuery (Email/UPN, Dimension Access).
2. Expand each table by the whole dimension if the access level is all (`*`). This can be performed in PowerQuery by adding a custom column: `if [dimension_access] = "*" then dimension_values_list else {dimension_access}`. Here, `[dimension_access]` would just be a reference the respective permissions column for that table. `dimensions_values_list` would be a list of all potential values for that dimension. The else statement returns the current `dimension_access` member in curly brackets to convert it to a single-member list.
3. Expand the list column.
4. Load changes to the model.
5. Set RLS rules accordingly on each new dimension RLS table.
6. Create bi-directional relationships between the expanded column of each new RLS table and the respective primary key of each dimension table. Check the "Apply security filter in both directions" box when creating.